# JTable not showing more than 5 columns

Tags: java, swing, sql-server-2008, netbeans, jtable

i need to show data from tables via JTABLE , i googled for hours , finally successfully find the code to do this, and it is working fine but there is an issue which is from netbeans i think

This is my table
[image]

it got 6 columns,

and this is my jtable
[image]

and this is the result
[image]

now before posting over here i tried my best to google or read oracle documentation about jtables, cant find any thing regarding this weird issue, 
if i use 4 columns, it show 4 columns data, i increased 1 column from design and it started showing 5 columns data ( perfect ) when i finally added 1 more last column, it is still showing 5 column data

and here is the code

```
   try {
        MyConnection mc = new MyConnection();
        Class.forName(mc.driver);
        Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(mc.login);
        Statement smt = connect.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = smt.executeQuery("select * from library_member");
        ResultSetMetaData rsmeta = rs.getMetaData();
        int columns = rsmeta.getColumnCount();
        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
        Vector columns_name = new Vector(), data_rows = new Vector();

        for(int i = 1; i < columns; i++){
            columns_name.addElement(rsmeta.getColumnName(i));
        }

        dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns_name);

        while(rs.next()){
            data_rows = new Vector();
            for(int j = 1; j < columns; j++){
                data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
            }
            dtm.addRow(data_rows);
        }

        jTable1.setModel(dtm);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

P.S the column it is not showing i think because member_email got 1 null value, if it is true , how should allow it,

QUESTION !! : how to increase the rowCount from 4? its uneditable in netbeans designview and i dont have enough time to create a jtable by myself

---

I updated member_email at member_id=2, still not showing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your not counting correctly.  Change the i = 1 to i = 0 in the for loop.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){
        columns_name.addElement(rsmeta.getColumnName(i+1));
    }
```

As well as here:

```
        for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++){
            data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j+1));

        }
```

Also note MadProgrammer's comment that JDBC row indexes start at 1, not 0.  That is why you also need getColumnName(i+1) and getString(j+1).

Or you can start counting at 1 in your loops and test <= columns like:

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= columns; i++){
        columns_name.addElement(rsmeta.getColumnName(i));
    }
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, JDBC tends to be `1` indexed, so `rsmeta.getColumnName(i)` should now be `rsmeta.getColumnName(i + 1)` or you can change `for(int i = 0; i < columns; i++){` to `for(int i = 1; i <= columns; i++){` either way...